# Sort data.frame by multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I know sorting data frames has been discussed endlessly, however I can't find an answer to my particular problem so I hope you don't mind me starting up the topic again…
Here's the problem: I have a data frame with many columns and want to sort it using all the columns without prioritising any columns (i.e.not sorting by 1st column, THEN 2nd etc.)

I tried order, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.
Here an example:

```
1  1 0 8 1
2  4 2 9 1
3  8 0 0 2
4  0 0 3 1
5  0 0 0 2
6  5 7 2 9
7  1 0 0 0
```

Preferred output:

```
1  5 7 2 9
2  4 2 9 1
3  1 0 8 1
4  8 0 0 2
5  0 0 3 1
6  0 0 0 2
7  1 0 0 0
```

Sorry for not being more specific, but I hope the example roughly explains what I want.
Note that my data frame has 5000 rows and 15 columns (all numerical).

Comment: You need to be more clear. Your example doesn't explain what you want.

Comment: What is your sort criteria for the preferred output? Is it sum of all columns, or something like that?

Comment: Not sure what you're after, but `DF[order(rowSums(DF), decreasing = T), ]` seems to match your output.

Comment: This is known as a "sort data.frame by multiple *rows* in R"

Comment: I took it to be sort-by-sorted-row-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat[ rev(order(     # need to reverse the default increasing order result
       apply(dat,1,function(x) 
          paste(sprintf("%05.0f", sort(x)), collapse=".") ) )) , ]
```

I know there is a school of though that naked code is not enough but I think once you learn to think from the inside outwards with R's functional paradigm, that most reasonably simple functions are self-documenting: Read this as  1) sort values within rows rows; 2] concatenate sorted values with leading zeroes to allow character sorting; 3) use the character index as the ordering. It occurred to me that you may need to wrap an `sprintf()` around the sorted numeric value to prevent "2" from being more "10" in anything other than a toy example.

```
> sprintf("%05.0f", 10)
#[1] "00010"

dat <- read.table(text="1  1 0 8 1
 2  4 2 9 1
 3  8 0 0 2
 4  0 0 3 1
 5  0 0 0 2
 6  5 7 2 9
 7  1 0 0 0")[-1]
dat[ rev(order( apply(dat,1,function(x) paste(sprintf("%05.0f", sort(x)), collapse=".") ) )) , ]
  V2 V3 V4 V5
6  5  7  2  9
2  4  2  9  1
1  1  0  8  1
3  8  0  0  2
4  0  0  3  1
5  0  0  0  2
7  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and sorry for not being more clear.
The last answer was exactly what I was after, thanks heaps!!

Comment: The SO way to give favorable feedback is with checkmarks and upvotes.